# Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{{1-e^{-{\sqrt{t}}}}}}$

Tags: exponential-function, laplace-transform

I want to evaluate the following Laplace transform:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-st}}{\sqrt{{1-e^{-{\sqrt{t}}}}}}dt$$

I tried using the substitution method, but it led me nowhere. I think the problem is arising because of the square root function.

I even tried integrating the function

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{{1-e^{-\sqrt{t}}}}}dt$$

but it was of no luck. I am not able to understand how to proceed with the problem.

I have been using Mathematica for awhile now, but it returns the same expression. I can get a numerical answer for it using Mathematica, but I was wondering if there exists a functional form of the Laplace transform. 
Is it possible to get the expression in the Laplace domain for this particular function?

I was looking up for the conditions that make the Laplace transform exist. But, the conditions are satisfied by this particular function.

Comment: Please format your question properly, make the title agree with the body and include your own work.

Comment: Thank you, I have made some changes. I tried working with different approaches, but I can't understand how to proceed with the integral.

Comment: @YourongZang: we may still consider the Laplace transform of unbounded functions in a right neighbourhood of the origin. For instance, the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{s}}$. This case is similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may start with the formal power series of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}x^n$$
in order to get
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-e^{-\sqrt{t}}}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}e^{-n\sqrt{t}}$$
and
$$\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-e^{-\sqrt{t}}}}\right)(s) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\int_{0}^{+\infty}2u e^{-(nu+su^2)}\,du $$
which equals
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\left(    \frac{1}{s}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } n e^{\frac{n^2}{4 s}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{n}{2 \sqrt{s}}\right)}{2 s^{3/2}}\right)$$
with a similar behaviour on $\mathbb{R}^+$ to the one of $s^{-3/4}$.